# template for creating functions in the master database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions, sql-server-2016, functions

I need to create functions in the master database, and I am developing a template for that, I want first to check if the function already exists, if not create a dummy function.

then grant all the relevant permissions to this dummy function.

the third step is to alter the function to the proper code.

the code that I am using:

```
USE [master]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE compatibility_level < 80)
    RAISERROR ('fn_keepOnlyTheNumbers cannot be installed when databases are in pre-2000 compatibility mode. For information: https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/22336/marcello-miorelli', 10,1) WITH LOG, NOWAIT;
GO


--- create the dummy version of the function
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.fn_keepOnlyTheNumbers') IS NULL
  EXEC ('

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_keepOnlyTheNumbers
(
  @TXT VARCHAR(4000)
 )
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS BEGIN RETURN  ''foo bar'' END;  

  ')
GO
```

but while doing this I am getting this error message while testing:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_keepOnlyTheNumbers('asdf1234a1s2d3f4@@@')
```

[image]

checking out what is going on

```
select * from sys.objects
where name like '%fn_keepOnly%'
```

[image]

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code created a SCALAR value function that returns a single value, not a TABLE value function that returns an entire table.

the correct syntax for the select is

```
SELECT dbo.fn_keepOnlyTheNumbers('asdf1234a1s2d3f4@@@')
```